# Algorithmn for converting numeric(decimal) to IPv6 address type

Tags: algorithm

What is the algorithm used to *convert back IPv6 address from numeric* (decimal) format?

I need to convert

```
42540488177518850335786991633549033211
```

to Ipv6 address type i.e.

```
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:0063:0000:0000:FEFB
```

Answer (score 1):

The IPv6 address is a 16 byte number, usually represented as a hex encoded string, with every pair of bytes separated by a colon.

So, to convert your number into the the hex-encoded format, you have to first convert the number to hex, then insert he colons.

Depending on the programming language you're using you might already have access to built-in or library functions that can hex-encode an arbitrary number. If not, the process is pretty simple:

- take the number and keep dividing by 16, keeping track of the reminder
- each of the reminders represents each one of the bytes
- each byte has to be hex-encode (ie. printed as a number ranging from 00 to FF
- start concatenating the numbers that you get, appending each new value to the left
- every other byte, insert a colon